# access dll function on C project from Ruby

Tags: c, ruby, dll, ffi, fiddle

I have a project written in C controlling hardware devices. I'm trying to access DLL functions in my projects from a Ruby app in order to control the hardware from the Ruby web app. I'm failing in loading the dll project files using FFI and Fiddle. Does anyone have an example I can use to share of a similar case?

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest taking a look at this http://swig.org

Comment: @shadowsheep SWIG is used for creating extensions though and I'm looking to just load a dll file into my Ruby app and use the functions in it. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Nope! You can use swig to auto generate ruby wrapoer for your dll like that http://web.mit.edu/svn/src/swig-1.3.25/Examples/ruby/class/index.html

Comment: See at the tutorial http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html sorry I don’t answer with a live example ‘cause are on my mobile right now.

Comment: Oh cool! O.k thank you! :)

Comment: U’r welcome! Happy learning!

Comment: I've posted an answer for OSX, I hope could help

Comment: It does, Thank you!!

Comment: So if it answers your question, could you flag it as the accepted one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using SWIG (http://swig.org)

I'll give you an example on OSX but you could find the equivalent on Windows as well.

Let's say you have a library (in my case hello.bundle or in your case hello.DLL) with this header file `hello.h`

```
#ifndef __HELLO__
#define __HELLO__

extern void say_hello(void); 

#endif
```

and you wanna call `say_hello` from a ruby program like that run.rb:

```
# file: run.rb
require 'hello'

# Call a c function
Hello.say_hello
```

(Pay attention here that the module name is Capitalised)

what you have to do is to create a file `hello.i` like that:

```
%module hello
 %{
 #include "hello.h"
 %}

 // Parse the original header file
 %include "hello.h"
```

And then run the command:

```
swig -ruby hello.i
```

This will generate a file `.c` that is a wrapper that will be installed as a wrapper module for your ruby environment: `hello_wrap.c`.

Then you need to create a file `extconf.rb` with this content:

```
require 'mkmf'
create_makefile('hello')
```

Pay attention that here "hello" is the name of our module in the file `.i`.

Then you must run `ruby extconf.rb` that will generate a Makefile.

```
ruby extconf.rb    
creating Makefile
```

Then you must type `make` that will compile the `_wrap.c` file against the library (in my case .bundle in your case .DLL).

```
make
compiling hello_wrap.c
linking shared-object hello.bundle
```

Now you must type `make install` (or sudo make install on Unix/Osx)

```
sudo make install
Password:
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 hello.bundle /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/universal-darwin17
```

Then you can run your program run.rb

```
ruby run.rb 
Hello, world!
```

I'll paste here below the `.c` file used to generate the library hello.bundle

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "hello.h"

void say_hello(void) {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    return;
}
```

If you leave this file along with it's `.h` file the Makefile will build the library for you

```
make
compiling hello.c
compiling hello_wrap.c
linking shared-object hello.bundle
```